# Checking if URL has similar substring in webview android

Tags: android, string, url, android-webview, substring

I want to check if the URL has the same substring so that I could do something while it is loading. Currently this is what I have:

```
if (Uri.parse(url).getPath().equals("/amodule/Magicalwebpage.php")) {

                // I will do something here
                //return true;
            }
```

What this basically does is that this just checks if my URL is perfectly equal to that what I am searching for. What I want it to compare is that it will check the URL if that url has the same word/phrase (in this case the word "Magical")as the one I am searching for.

How do I compare my URL to see if it has the substring Magical in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    if (Uri.parse(url).getPath().contains("Magical")) {

        // I will do something here
        //return true;

    }
```